# How to prove this simple inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Please help me to prove this inequality.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $EX=EY=0$, then we must have $E(|X|) \leq E(|X+Y|)$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition $EX=0$ is not necessary.

Since the absolute value function is convex, by [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) for [conditional expectations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation), 
$$E \big(|X+Y|\big| X\big)\ge |E \big(X+Y\big| X\big)|=|X+E \big(Y\big| X\big)|.\tag{1}$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, 
$$E\big(Y\big| X\big)=EY=0.\tag{2}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, it follows that
$$E(|X+Y|)=E\left(E \big(|X+Y|\big| X\big)\right)\ge E\left(|X+E \big(Y\big| X\big)|\right)=E(|X|).$$